# How can I setup a bash script to open a cli, then input a command into that cli

Tags: command-line, server, bash, scripts, ssh

I have set up an SSH connection between my home workstation and my work laptop. I want to make a script that I can launch as a desktop application that will open up the CLI and execute the login command with the relevant ip address of my workstation.

I'm not sure how I can go about this though and I couldn't find anything online (although I probably don't know enough to be searching for the right thing).

I have also heard something about keys being used, and a guide I was following had me make one (although I had to give up on it as it kept mixing up which commands to put into the workstation, and which were to the laptop for remote access). I have generated the keys, but I have no idea how to make them work, or how they work. If anyone has a layman's explanation I would appreciate the opportunity to learn more.

Any help with this would be great.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a 'shortcut' just like you have shortcut icons in windows. You will need to create a `.desktop` file.

Open up a text editor and create a file `ssh_shortcut.desktop` (any name should suffice.) You can save this file on a Desktop (doesn't matter)

Add the following content to the file

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=ssh_shortcut
Comment=Shortcut to ssh to a server
Exec=gnome-terminal -e 'ssh -X bob@192.168.1.1'
Icon=utilities-terminal
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Application;
```

*Note: Replace `bob` with the username and `192.168.1.1` with the IP of the server.*

Now, open up a terminal type cd Desktop and run the command `chmod +x ssh_shortcut.desktop` and you are good to go

Comment: oh yeah, I'm familiar with this. I am just not sure how to put together the bash script that would open the cli like ctrl + Alt + T, and then login to the workstation.

Comment: actually just found gnome-terminal; will play around with that.

Comment: @Andy why would you need a bash script?